What is the current through this resistor in small signal analysis?
This is circuit below (Note: \$V_T\$ is the AC signal)
Is the current through this transistor 0 in small ac analysis?

Does this equation below hold?
$$-V_x g_{m1} + \frac{V_F - V_X} {r_{o1}} = 0$$

Where is the AC stimulus applied?

@ThePhoton $V_T$ is the AC signal

@FrancescoM. $V_X = \frac{\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2} V_T } {1 + (R_1 \parallel R_2) g_{m1}}$ Is this what you mean? How do you derive this? Can you write original KCl and KVL?

I neglected ro. Draw the equivalent circuit for incremental signals and apply Millmann's theorem to find Vx=Vs.

My equivalent circuit for incremental signals is the following, applying Millman's theorem we find VS:


I think current source should be removed (open circuit) in small signal analysis.

You could also do a more in-depth analysis by applying the methods of electrical engineering, for example from the following analysis. From it you can create a model to apply to all (small) networks:


The problem is that OP (and some of the responders) are confusing small signal and large signal analysis.
To find IT (which I believe is the goal) all components must be replaced by their small signal equivalents. DC voltage sources are shorts (done correctly in the original questio) and DC current sources are opens. The MOSFET model contains an open circuit (across which vgs is defined) and a dependent current source (with parallel resistor ro if output resistance is considered).
It then becomes a one-equation problem. No matrices needed.
By the way using Vx AND VX confuses things also.

Can your own KVL and KCL equation

The goal is to find the gain ($$\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}}$$)
